# Unable to play 1080p videos

Tags: 12.04, video, laptop, intel-graphics, hd-video

i am dual booting windows and ubuntu (12.04), and i am unable to play any videos(1080p) on it , while on windows everything works fine. 
   I have -
-tried different media players (vlc, movie player etc)
- tried to tweak performance settings after installing jupiter since i thought there might me some issues with power management
- tweaking possible options in vlc (hardware ones)
-removing and disabling any application which i found could be the cause of bug(when i searched the forums)

the machine is a dell latitude d630 ,dual core 32 bit at 1.8 ghz and 2 gb ram with discreet graphics intel 965GM .

Comment: Is it give you any error ?

Comment: More information is needed, do the listed video players give you an error message or do they just black screen?